# How to make MacVim remember its zoom level

Tags: macvim

Every time I open the MacVim, the font size of its contents are just too small to read. So I have to zoom in (with `Command + +`) several time before editing stuff.

The problem is it doesn't remember its zoom level when next time I open the MacVim, I have to do the zoom in actions again...

Any helps are welcome!

mitnk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make the settings permanent try adding something like the following lines to your .vimrc file. Those lines below will tell MacVim to set the font and the fontsize you would like to use by default. For more information do `:help guifont` from within a normal mode buffer in MacVim.

```
"Set the guifont
:set guifont=Menlo:h12
```